# Actualizar el Value de mi input date al usuario cambiar la fecha, asi se actualize el contador de dias

Tags: javascript, html, html5, date, datetime

Lo que intento es cambiar el valor de mi input en la fecha, para que cuando el usuario actualize la fecha a la que necesita saber cuanto falta, este dato se actualize hacia Javascript(Es un countdown personalizable). Entiendo que necesito encontrar algun metodo que agregarle a Value por que de ahi toma en Javascript el dato de fecha para calcular la distancia hacia la dicha. Me intersaria hacerlo en Vainilla Javascript

```
//let dateControl = document.getElementById('myDate').value('YYYY-MM-DD');//
let dateControl = document.getElementById('myDate').value;
let countDownDate = new Date(dateControl).getTime();
//let countDownDate = new Date('Oct 15    , 2023 15:37:25').getTime();

let x = setInterval(function() {
   
    let now = new Date().getTime();


    let distance = countDownDate - now;

    //var seconds = 1000;
    //var minutes = seconds * 60;
    //var hours = minutes * 60;
    //var days = hours * 24;
    //var timer;//

    
    let days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 ));
    let hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 *24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    let minutes = Math.floor ((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000*60));
    let seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
    
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = days + ' d ' + hours + ' h '
    + minutes + ' m ' + seconds + ' s '

    if (distance < 0 ) {
        clearInterval(x);
        document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = 'READY';
    }

}, 1000);


}

countdown();

HTML 

----------

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Countdown</title>
    <script defer src="./countdown.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./styles.css" />
    
</head>

<body> 


    <h2>
   
    <label for="start">End date</label>

 <input type="datetime-local" id="myDate" name="trip-start"
       value="2023-10-15T12:00" 
       min="2022-01-18" max="2030-12-31"
      
       
       >
      
     

    </h2>

    <p id="demo"></p>
```

Ahi esta mi codigo, a todo esto soy novato este es mi primero proyecto y me eh metido en un lio con esto de las fechas jajaja. Espero sepan ayudarme.

Comment: agrega el documento html tambien, lee [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida.

Comment: el html esta abajo !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahí te adjunto una solución decime si te sirvió y si es lo que buscabas, intente comentar todo para que te hagas una idea de que hago:

```js
    const date = document.getElementById('myDate'); // seleccionamos input y demo
    const demo = document.getElementById('demo');
    let timer; // el timer lo declaramos fuera de la funcion para que cada vez que llamamos a dicha funcion este timer se sobreescriba constantemente.
    // esto evita que se nos creen varios timers cada vez que cambiamos la fecha
    
    function countdown(){
      let dateControl = date.value;
      timer = setInterval(() => { // redefinimos el timer
        let distance = new Date(dateControl).getTime() - new Date().getTime(); // esto estaba bien solo lo resumi intentando usar menos lineas de codigo
        demo.textContent = // lo correcto seria textContent, innerHTML se usa para agregar etiquetas
         `${Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24))} d 
          ${Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60))} h 
          ${Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60))} m 
          ${Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000)} s`
        if (distance < 0) { // al terminar la cuenta atras:
          clearInterval(timer); // limpiamos timer
          demo.textContent = 'READY'; // mensaje de finalizacion
        }
      }, 1000);
    }
    
    date.addEventListener("change",() => { // al cambiar el input de la fecha:
      clearInterval(timer) // limpiamos el timer
      demo.textContent = 'UPDATING COUNTDOWN...' // mensaje de transicion
      countdown(); // llamamos a la funcion contdown, que nos creara otro timer con la nueva fecha, sobreescribiendo a la anterior
    })
    
    // apenas se carga la pagina:
    demo.textContent = 'STARTING...' 
    countdown();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css" />
    <title>Hospital XYZ</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>
      <label for="start">End date</label>
      <input
        type="datetime-local"
        id="myDate"
        name="trip-start"
        value="2023-10-15T12:00"
        min="2022-01-18"
        max="2030-12-31"
      />
    </h2>
    <p id="demo"></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Pregunta cualquier duda. Uso un evento para llamar a una función que haga lo que quiero (en este caso actualizar la cuenta atrás).

Comment: Rey muchisimas gracias por la ayuda! Me ayudaste a comprender mucho mejor esto las anotaciones fueron de gran ayuda. Sos un genio muchas gracias de verdad!

Comment: @user312892 ya me habia olvidado de esta respuesta :D de nada!